# Limitar la reproducción a una sola canción a la vez con JavaScript

Tags: jquery, html5

No consigo limitar la reproducción para que no suenen varias canciones a la vez.

Con mi código si está sonando la canción 1 y pulso en la canción 2 la primera se para pero la segunda no se reproduce hasta pulsar otra vez. Luego pasa que si son muchas canciones voy a repetir mucho código.

```js
var playing = false;

$('#play1').click(function()
{
   if(!playing)
    {
     audio1.play();
     audio2.pause();
     playing = true;
   } 
   else 
   {
     audio1.pause();
     audio2.pause();
     playing = false;
   }  
});


$('#play2').click(function()
 {
   if(!playing)
    {
     audio2.play();
     audio1.pause();
     playing = true;
   } 
   else 
   {
     audio2.pause();
  //   audio1.pause();
     playing = false;
   }  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li id="play1" class="playAudio" data-audio="1">Play audio #1</li>
  <li>-------------</li>
  <li id="play2" class="playAudio" data-audio="2">Play audio #2</li>
  <li>-------------</li>
  <li id="play3" class="playAudio" data-audio="3">Play audio #3</li>
</ul>

<audio id="audio1">
  <source src="http://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-1.mp3">
</audio>
<audio id="audio2">
  <source src="http://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-2.mp3">
</audio>
<audio id="audio3">
  <source src="http://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-4.mp3">
</audio>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
//**** código de: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19792168/2097224

document.addEventListener('play', function(e){
    var audios = document.getElementsByTagName('audio');
    for(var i = 0, len = audios.length; i < len;i++){
        if(audios[i] != e.target){
            audios[i].pause();
        }
    }
}, true);

//****


$(document).on('click', '.playAudio', function(){ 
  
  var whichAudio = $('#audio' + $(this).data('audio')); 
  
  whichAudio[0].paused ? whichAudio[0].play() : whichAudio[0].pause();
   
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li id="play1" class="playAudio" data-audio="1">Play audio #1</li>
  <li>-------------</li>
  <li id="play2" class="playAudio" data-audio="2">Play audio #2</li>
  <li>-------------</li>
  <li id="play3" class="playAudio" data-audio="3">Play audio #3</li>
</ul>

<audio id="audio1">
  <source src="http://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-1.mp3">
</audio>
<audio id="audio2">
  <source src="http://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-2.mp3">
</audio>
<audio id="audio3">
  <source src="http://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-4.mp3">
</audio>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ejecutando esta función creo que lograrás lo que buscas.

```
$(".playAudio").click(function(){
    var audios = $("audio");
    for (var i = 0; i < audios.length; i++) {
        audios[i].pause();
        audios[i].currentTime = 0;
    }
    var audioId = "audio" + $(this).data().audio;
    console.log(audioId)
    document.getElementById(audioId).play();
});
```